# Brightness Control inverted? ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, brightness

I recently update my ubuntu kernal to 5.10.13-051013-generic after the installation , when i press my brightness key to increase it will decrease the screen brightness , graphical control slider also like that? What happened here please Help

```
neofetch 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               rjay@rjay-HP-15-Notebook-PC 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: HP 15 Notebook PC 096E10000040 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.10.13-051013-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 1 min 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2100 (dpkg), 17 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1366x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Pentium N3530 (4) @ 2.582 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1555MiB / 3810MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel looks like it has been manually installed, since this is not an officially supported kernel version for Ubuntu 20.04.2. I would suggest sticking to the supported kernel versions by Canonical (should be 5.8 for 20.04.2) - `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`

Comment: How can i reinstall the latest official kernal

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04` should be enough. Make sure not to start your 5.10 kernel when rebooting your system.

Comment: do i need to uninstall my current kernal and reinstall ofiicial supported kernal

Comment: Once you've confirmed that the 5.8 kernel is working you can remove this 5.10 kernel from your system.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04
[sudo] password for rjay: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04'

Comment: Seems like `xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04` is no longer a thing. Just ignore it then.

Comment: Yes it worked Thank you 

Comment: noo it  doesnt worked

Comment: i execute your command and it shows successfully installed without error. But after installation i restart my system and again check my neofetch command it again shows the kernal 5.10.13-051013-generic

Comment: You need to hold the shift key during boot the get to the GRUB menu where you can select which kernel to boot.

Comment: Yes i can boot into 5.8 kernal from grub now neofetch shows 5.8  . But the brightness problem still exist